# What is GPS,AGPS,LBS in android?

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I'm working in android (developing application for mobile and tablets). I am using **android version is 2.2.**

In my application, I want to capture the longtitude,latitude.
My suprevisor is said to me capture the locations using **GPS,AGPS,LBS**

I'm new to android .I does not know GPS,AGPS,LBS.

Please send me the details, what are the difference,advantages,disadvantages of these 3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't compare LBS with GPS and AGPS. LBS stands for Location based services . It's a service done with the help of GPS/AGPS . For example 'Requesting the nearest business or service, such as an ATM or restaurant' is a service required by a user. There are many applications available for to provide above service. Those application will use either GPS/AGPS to find the location and service to user based on the location fetched.

So simply any application which use location to serve users are considered as LBS.

Following is the difference between GPS and AGPS

The difference between GPS and A-GPS is actually pretty straightforward. A GPS phone comes with a built-in GPS chip. GPS, short for Global Positioning System, is typically used to determine the location, speed, direction and time of the device. So, for example, in the case of the Mobile, when GPS is activated on the unit, the system would be able to triangulate the position of the receiver when three or more satellites are connected. And since it is able to calculate speed and direction, GPS is also commonly used as a navigation device while driving.

A-GPS (Assisted-GPS), on the other hand, was developed to enhance the performance of GPS. This is especially useful in environments where the GPS chip may have difficulty in getting a satellite signal, such as an urban canyon, or places where there is too much overhead obstruction. What A-GPS does is it leverages on an intermediary called an Assistant Server which provides information on cell ID or other data to help the device identify the right satellites to connect to. This shortens the time needed for a location lock although certain A-GPS solutions require an active connection to a cell phone network.

**Pros and Cons of GPS and AGPS:**

The realiability and Accuracy is high in the GPS and it is low in AGPS.

The location captured by AGPS is not as accurate as GPS.

The location capturing via GPS is time consuming and power (Battery) consuming, etc.

Hope it helps. For more details on [A-GPS](https://medium.com/ivymobility-developers/understanding-agps-assisted-gps-3ae23cc691ab)

Comment: The reliability and accuracy is high in GPS than AGPS.The location capturing via GPS is More accurate than AGPS.The location capturing in GPS is time consuming and power (Battery) consuming,etc.

Answer (score 7):

- GPS - Global positioning system -> get your location via satellites
- AGPS - Assisted GPS -> get your location via satellites and network providers
- LBS - Location Based Services -> doesn't have much to do with getting your location.

Basically, in Android you can get your location using following providers:

Network: get your location based on your wifi connection. fairly fast, but not so accurate
GPS: get your location based on GPS receiver. fairly slow, but quite accurate

so you have a trade-off: either to use Network provider and get your results fast, or to use GPS provider and get more accurate data.

Read more here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 4):

**LBS** - Location Based Services

**GPS** - Global Positioning System

**AGPS** - Assisted Global Positioning System

**LBS**

As abbas.aniefa said, We can't say differences of LBS over GPS and AGPS. It is the service which uses GPS/AGPS to find location. Android provides a number of building blocks for location based services.

**GPS**

GPS, the Global Positioning System run by the United States Military. 
This provider determines location using satellites. 
Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix.

*Advantages*

- It will give our location accurately,
- It will work fine in out-door locations.

*Disadvantages*

- It may be very very slow in in-door locations,
- It will quickly drain battery.
- It will be slower than network provider.

**A-GPS**

A-GPS - Assited GPS. Normal GPS can take a long time to get a position fix. For this reason most cell phone companies have the GPS in the phone turned off except for emergency calls and for services they sell you (such as directions).

A-GPS will come under network location provider category because it uses GPS chip on device, as well as assistance from the network (cellular network) to provide a fast initial fix.

*Advantages*

- It will give our location  very accurately in-door location itself,
- Drainage of battery will be saved,
- It will be faster than GPS Provider.

*Disadvantage*

- We can not use it with GPS alone. It will depend on network connection.

**Over all Differences of GPS and A-GPS**

*GPS*

1. Uses GPS chip on the device,
2. Line of sight to the satellites,
3. Need about 7 to get a fix,
4. Takes a long time to get a fix,
5. Doesn’t work around tall buildings.

*A-GPS*

1. Uses GPS chip on device, as well as assistance from the network (cellular network) to provide a fast initial fix,
2. Very low power consumption,
3. Very accurate,
4. Works without any line of sight to the sky,
5. Depends on carrier and phone supporting this (even if phone supports it, and network does not then this does not work).

Answer (score 0):

I think GPS is done/processed via satellite communication without any network service provider.

The AGPS is done/processed via the network (which is provided by service provider such as Airtel,Vodafone,etc).We should pay for service provider for usage of network.

The LBS is processed through the AGPS.

I dont know whether my points are correct or not.Im heard from others and put it.

All are welcome to give their suggestions,ideas,etc.

Comment: Have to say that your points are incorrect. Please read the answer by droid.dev.